# Android ble auto disconnect

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Android OS：6.0
APP：nRF Connect for Mobile, and own application

A device conneted Android Ble. A few minutes later, the device automatically disconnected. Is the hardware device or app problem？ How to solve this problem？

Answer (score 1):

There are three reasons a device disconnects if it is not actively disconnected by the app in the smartphone:

1. The connection times out due to radio interference or goes out of range and similar.
2. The peripheral actively disconnects.
3. Bluetooth is turned off on the smartphone.